# Dismissing the UIActivityIndicatorView on Background touch

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiactivityindicatorview

I am fetching the data from the web service and during the the data fetch I am displaying a `UIAcitivityIndicatorView` on the screen. This indicator is in `UIAlertView`

```
UIAlertView *waitAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Please Wait...." message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles: nil];

    [waitAlert show];

indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];

// Adjust the indicator so it is up a few pixels from the bottom of the alert
indicator.center = CGPointMake(waitAlert.bounds.size.width / 2, waitAlert.bounds.size.height - 50);
[waitAlert addSubview:indicator];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:URLString];

    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(startAnimation) toTarget:self withObject:self.view];


    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
     {
      // Data to populate the tableview
      [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^ {

             [self.tableView1 reloadData];
             //Stop the UIActivitiyIndicatorView
             [self stopLoading];

         }];
}];
```

I am able to dismiss that successfully when the data loads successfully but I want to dismiss the `UIActivityIndicatorView` if someone touches on the rest of the screen during the data load from the web service. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

can you try this

After showing UIAlertView add view to your view controller (or even window) new empty UIView with full screen size. Attach to this view with UITapGestureRecognizer

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
[view addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
[singleTap release];

-(void)handleSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender{
    [myAlert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
    [view removeFromSuperView];
}
```

Comment: but it is not working as this method is not called perhaps UIAlertView is not allowing it to touch on background

Comment: yes it will not work for uialertview .you can set your own alert

Comment: - (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    [self dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:index animated:YES];
}


can you try with this

Comment: If I add UITapGestureRecognizer on UIAlertView then it is dismissing but when I add it on view then I won't work. Is there any method so that it can work on view also

Comment: please see the above edited code.
you need to subview view in alert rite?

Comment: didn't got your last comment but UIActivityIndicatorView is on UIAlertView

Comment: add uiview in alert view with clear color and then add gestures .so it will work

Comment: still it is working on the touch on uialertview but not outside

Comment: **dont add gesture on alert view .**
`[waitAlert addSubview:empty_view];`
`UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
[empty_view addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
[singleTap release];`
</br>
`-(void)handleSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender{
    [myAlert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
    [empty_view removeFromSuperView];
}`</br>

Comment: **dont add gesture on alert view .**
`[waitAlert addSubview:empty_view];`
`UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
[empty_view addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
[singleTap release];`

`-(void)handleSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender{
    [myAlert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
    [empty_view removeFromSuperView];
}`

Comment: still not working on background touch but working on the uialertview

Comment: please check whether you have added subview for your alert and view has gesture

Comment: I have done `UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
    UIView *aView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    [waitAlert addSubview:aView];
    [aView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
    
    

}

-(void)handleSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    NSLog(@"\n\n\n Single Tap");
    
    [self stopLoading];
    
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}`

Answer (score 0):

You can do that under following UIResponder methods
`-(void)touchesBegan` or
`-(void)touchesEnded`

and disable the `UIActivityIndicator` inside it.

Comment: There is no need to show UIAlertView and UIActivityIndicator together.

Comment: But in case if you want just check who is on top of UIResponder chain

Answer (score 0):

Use `touchesEnded` method

inside the touches ended method do functions for stop and remove `UIActivityIndicatorView`

```
-(void)touchesEnded

{

[indicator stopAnimating];

[indicator removeFromSuperView];

}
```